# How VIM Autocomplete Work

Tags: algorithm, unix, vim, data-structures, autocomplete

I was going over VIM shortcuts & found the **CTRL+p** which acts as an autocomplete in UNIX (you know what I am saying, a dropdown list of the possible words to use, sorted by frequency of usage). It seems to detect even the most immediately typed words. How does this work in VIM? **I am specifically interested in the data structures that are used for this?**

Is there some indexing going on, which dynamically keeps adding new words to its index as they are typed? It has saved me tons of time off-late. By the way VIM Rocks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beauty of a project like Vim is that it is open source. Instructions as to how you can download the source are on the [Vim Download](http://www.vim.org/download.php) page.

If you take a look at [`edit.c`](https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/src/edit.c), you'll find a struct called `compl_S`. That will be a good starting point if you want to understand how Vim's completion works.

Comment: I could do that. But I thought I could ask for a better explanation for our myriad experts here at SO :) That way maybe I could end up learning something more...

Comment: @movieyoda: Personally, I find that I learn a lot more by reading through code and actually playing with code rather than have somebody tell me what it does.